# Elements of $F( \alpha_1,..., \alpha_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are the elements of $F( \alpha_1,...,  \alpha_n)$ where $F$ is a field and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are the roots of a nonconstant polynomial $f \in F[X]$? Are the elements have the form $\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i\alpha_i}$ where $a_i \in F$? I don know how to see the element of a field after the field adjoints with some roots of a polynomial.

Comment: No. Try to write $\sqrt{6}$ as a linear combination of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: So it cannot be linear combination of all the adjoins roots. Then how we determine the form of elements in the set?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of all rational functions $q(\vec{x}) = n(\vec{x}) / d(\vec{x})$ in $n$ variables such that $d(\vec{\alpha}) \neq 0$.

$F$ is the field of all values $q(\vec{\alpha})$.

Because it's an algebraic extension, this turns out to be equal to the ring of all values $p(\vec{\alpha})$ where $p(\vec{x})$ is a polynomial in $n$ variables.